# How to get the value of special attributes / custom attributes of HTML using PHP DOM Parser?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, attributes

```
<li data-docid="thisisthevaluetoget" class="search-results-item">
</li>
```

How to get the value of "data-docid"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DOMDocument to get at the [attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes):

```
$html = '<li data-docid="thisisthevaluetoget" class="search-results-item"></li>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach ($node->attributes as $a) {
            echo $a->nodeName.': '.$a->nodeValue.'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this using JavaScript + jQuery. You may get the value and pass it into another php file using $_GET method.

an example is ***[here](http://jsfiddle.net/quKTK/1/)***

Comment: thanks blasteralfred but i have to use PHP DOM Parser for it. I'll try to find other solution. But thanks.