# Simple HTML DOM getting all attributes from a tag

Tags: php, html, dom

Sort of a two part question but maybe one answers the other.  I'm trying to get a piece of information out of an

```
<div id="foo">
<div class="bar"><a data1="xxxx" data2="xxxx" href="http://foo.bar">Inner text"</a>
<div class="bar2"><a data3="xxxx" data4="xxxx" href="http://foo.bar">more text"</a>
```

Here is what I'm using now.

```
$articles = array();
$html=file_get_html('http://foo.bar');
foreach($html->find('div[class=bar] a') as $a){
    $articles[] = array($a->href,$a->innertext);
}
```

This works perfectly to grab the href and the inner text from the first div class. I tried adding a $a->data1 to the foreach but that didn't work.

How do I grab those inner data tags at the same time I grab the href and innertext.

Also is there a good way to get both classes with one statement? I assume I could build the find off of the id and grab all the div information.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To grab all those attributes, you should before investigate the parsed element, like this:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=bar] a') as $a){
  var_dump($a->attr);
}
```

...and see if those attributes exist. They don't seem to be valid HTML, so maybe the parser discards them.

If they exist, you can read them like this:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=bar] a') as $a){
  $article = array($a->href, $a->innertext);
  if (isset($a->attr['data1'])) {
    $article['data1'] = $a->attr['data1'];
  }
  if (isset($a->attr['data2'])) {
    $article['data2'] = $a->attr['data2'];
  }
  //...
  $articles[] = $article;
}
```

To get both classes you can use a multiple selector, separated by a comma:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=bar] a, div[class=bar2] a') as $a){
...
```

Comment: Addition: if the classes really both start with the same prefix ("bar" in your example), this might work too for you: `div[class^=bar]` (meaning: class begins with "bar")

Comment: Thanks much. Not to be dense though..How do I assign that. What i mean is once I do the find that gets multiple div's what do I do with that? Do I still do assign that " as $a"? Sorry to be dense here.

Comment: Thanks ermanbob.  The multiple selector worked great.  I still can't seem to pull that custom <a> attribute, which is actually data-content-id.  I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830933/php-simple-html-dom-list-of-attributes but I'm not sure what to do with that last example to actually display the attributes.   I also was looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773940/how-to-get-the-value-of-special-attributes-custom-attributes-of-html-using-php but using that returns an error.  For both I'm feeding it with my $html=file_get_html('http://foo.bar'); line.

Comment: The first link you provided is very useful. I edited my answer again, to show you how to read those attributes.

Comment: Ermannob thank you so much! I didn't realize I could use the $a->attr!

Comment: I wanted to update this with what I hope is an easy follow up questions.  In the example above, foreach($html->find('div[class=bar] a, div[class=bar2] a') as $a){, I'm getting the data I want. I'm writing it to an array with $article = array($a->href, $a->innertext); ( I'm scraping Metafilter here just fyi. ) For the first selector there is only ever 1 match, but the second there can me multiple.  Since I'm writing it to a single array its not really usable because I cant associate the second selector items with the first. Multidimensional array? I've succeeded in just confusing myself. THanks

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old, but the OP asked how they could get all the attributes in one statement.   I just did this for a project I'm working on.

You can get all the attributes for an element with the `getAllAttributes()` method.  The results are automatically stored in an array property called `attr`.

In the example below I am grabbing all links but you can use this with whatever you want.   NOTE: This also works with `data-` attributes.   So if there is an attribute called `data-url` it will be accessible with `$e->attr['data-url']` after you run the `getAllAttributes` method.

In your case the attributes your looking for will be `$e->attr['data1']` and `$e->attr['data2']`.  Hope this helps someone if not the OP.

***Get all Attributes***

```
$html = file_get_html('somefile.html');
foreach ($html->find('a') as $e) {   //used a tag here, but use whatever you want
    $e->getAllAttributes();

    //testing that it worked
    print_r($e->attr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this code

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html('somefile.html');
foreach ($html->find('a') as $e) { 
$filter = $e->getAttribute('data-filter-string');
}
?>
```

Comment: A code only answer is not high quality.   Please edit your answer to explain your code.   Show how and why it answers the question.  Add links to any relevant documentation.

Comment: Hooray!
The 'attr' was returning me a PHP fatal error.
With 'getAttribute' I got it working.

Comment: clean solution, works as well

Answer (score 2):

```
$data1 = $html->find('.bar > a', 0)->attr['data1'];
$data2 = $html->find('.bar > a', 0)->attr['data2'];
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it