# using PHP simple html dom get attributes name in span?

Tags: html, simple-html-dom

I am not if 'tags' are the right term but i have to get the "data-time" values from this span into an array. How can I use simple html dom to get them?

Here is on span I am trying to get the "data-time" out of.

```
include('../simpleHtmlDom/simple_html_dom.php');

// Put the Twitters username here
$user = "yadayada";

$html = file_get_html("https://twitter.com/$user");
$ret = $html->find('div[class=ProfileTweet-contents]'); 
$ret = $html->find('p[class=ProfileTweet-text js-tweet-text u-dir]'); 

/// tries to get the time code but does only gets the span
$date = $html->find('span[class=js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp]', 0);

$DoesNotWork = $html->find( "data-time", 0 );


echo $ret[1]; // get's a users tweet. 

echo $DoesNotWork;
```

The result of the date

```
<span class="js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp"
    data-time="1401528672"
    data-long-form="true">
    15h
  </span>
```

I would think it is something like this but this code does not work.
$html->find( "data-time", 0 );

Comment: You can use regular expression, preg_match("/data-time=.*"/", $input_line, $output_array);

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access

Comment: You're talking about attributes, not tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the date using this code, tho I think there is a better way. I think it would be best to find a simple dom code that gets the text of the date-time in line

```
<span class"js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp" date-time="89393748474">
```

but instead I used two "list" php lines as seen below and that worked.

```
$dateTimes = array();
foreach ($html->find('div.GridTimeline .js-short-timestamp') as $value) {
    $dateTimes[] = $value->outertext;
}
//  These are the lines I get the date-time from.
list($Gone,$Keep) = explode("data-time=\"", $dateTimes[0]);
list($Date,$Gone) = explode("\"", $Keep);

$Date =  date('M d, Y', $Date);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
// Include the script
$url = 'https://twitter.com/yourusername';
$html = file_get_html($url);
$dateTimes = array();
foreach ($html->find('div.GridTimeline .js-short-timestamp') as $value) {
    $dateTimes[] = $value->innertext;
}
```

Result of `print_r($dateTimes);`:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>      2h   
    [1] =>      2h   
    [2] =>      2h   
    // Truncated...
    [10] =>      11h   
    [11] =>      May 30   
    [12] =>      May 30   
    [13] =>      May 6   
    // Truncated...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use:

```
$html->find( "[data-time]", 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone landing here in 2021, following no 1 google search result:

Unless I misinterpreted your intention, you might achieve what you want using (with simplehtmldom):

```
$html->find('span[data-time]')->attr[data-time];
```

The official simplehtmldom documentation fails to mention that. However,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456823/10050838 is one possible source.