# Get inner text of span tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a span tag that is being scraped and stored in a field in the database. The tag looks like this:

```
<span class="datetime" data-val-utcdate="2014-07-14T15:53:18.3370000Z">11:53 AM</span>
```

I'd like to be able to grab the `XX:XX XM` out of the span tag. I am a beginner with regular expressions though. What is the best way to extract that?

Comment: Would this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456621/simple-html-dom-getting-all-attributes-from-a-tag?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get a DateTime object from the span value, you can use http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.createfromformat.php.

```
$string = '11:53 AM';
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $string);
```

Comment: That doesn't tell them how to get that vale from the HTML

Comment: He asked about how to parse the value, not getting it.

Comment: `I'd like to be able to grab the XX:XX XM out of the span tag` <-- I disagree

Comment: "I completely stink at ever getting regex to work properly for me"

Comment: Right, for parsing HTML. Which is why you shouldn't use regex's for parsing HTML.

Comment: Did I say to use a regex ? Stop trying to recover your mistake.

Comment: @epicdev - John is sort of right. In order for me to work with the function, I need to be able to know the string, and without extracting the string from the span tag - I won't ever know what it is to add to the string.