# how to extract tag attributes with Simple html dom ?

Tags: php, html

I an trying to extract information using simple_html_dom.php

The line looks like this:

`<meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su 08:00-00:00">`

I need the "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su 08:00-00:00" part.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
$url="https://www1.shoppersdrugmart.ca/en/store-locator/store/668"; 
include ('../classes/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($url);

//this works fine
$eg = $html->find('dd[itemprop="telephone"]');
echo "Phone: ".$eg[0]->plaintext. "<br>";

//this does not work
$eg = $html->find('meta[itemprop="openingHours"]');
echo "openingHours: ". $eg['content']->plaintext. "<br>";

$oh_content=$html->find('meta[itemprop="openingHours"]')->attr("content");
echo $oh_content."*<br>";

$oh_content1=$html->find('meta[itemprop="openingHours"]')->content;
echo $oh_content1."*<br>";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456621/simple-html-dom-getting-all-attributes-from-a-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in `$eg = $html->find('dd[itemprop="telephone"]');` `$eg` is **array** of filtered nodes, then it is **true** for your second `find`:

```
$eg = $html->find('meta[itemprop="openingHours"]');  
// $eg is array:
var_dump($eg[0]->content);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need it, here is the code that works:

```
$url="https://www1.shoppersdrugmart.ca/en/store-locator/store/668"; 
include ('../classes/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($url);

$eg = $html->find('dd[itemprop="telephone"]');
echo "Phone: ".$eg[0]->plaintext. "<br>";

$eg = $html->find('meta[itemprop="openingHours"]');
echo "openingHours: ". $eg[0]->content. "<br>";
```